# Laravel and Vagrant: Don't have /home/vagrant folder

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, vagrant

I've successfully created a **laravel** app with the `$ laravel new blog` command on my *Ubuntu 16.04*. All app files are located at the `~/Code` folder.

Here's my **Homestead.yaml** file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: devbase.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/blog/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

The problem is I don't have this `/home/vagrant` folder on my computer. And, of course, the **blog** app source files are not shared to this folder.

Do I have to manually create this folder? And how to make the `~/Code` folder share files with it then?

Or there occurred a problem while installing **VirtualBox**, **Vagrant** or **Homestead**?

What I have to do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to have `/home/vagrant` on your machine, it's the folder inside vagrant box (Homestead). Run `vagrant ssh` (password is `vagrant`) command to connect to the VM and you'll find `/home/vagrant` directory there.

Comment: Oh, man, thanks. Asking stupid questions always was my main problem)